# My Plotly animated chart is saying The 'name' property is a string and must be specified as String

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Plotly is throwing a weird looking error, which IN don't really understand.

Here is my code.

```
print(df_geo.dtypes)

import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(df_geo, x="Exp_Month", y="Rev_Month", animation_frame="Volume", animation_group="Site_Name",
           size="Volume", color="Market", hover_name="Market",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,1000000], range_y=[2,100000])
```

Here is the error message.

```
Invalid value of type {typ} received for the '{name}' property of {pname}

ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp' received for the 'name' property of frame
        Received value: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')

    The 'name' property is a string and must be specified as:
      - A string
      - A number that will be converted to a string
```

I thought maybe Exp_Month or Rev_Month had some weird characters, so I sorted ascending and descending, but didn't see anything wrong. Also, both of these fields are datetime64[ns]. Volume is float64 and both Site_Name and Market are object. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error has something to do with the time format. When I passed in a different date format, it worked. This was my solution.

```
from datetime import datetime
def convert_datetime(dt):
    return datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')

df_geo['Exp_Month']= df_geo['Exp_Month'].apply(convert_datetime)
df_geo['Rev_Month']= df_geo['Rev_Month'].apply(convert_datetime)
```